# Detecting an iphones available memory

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to detect an iphones available memory so that when your app runs it can remind the user to restart, depending if the memory is low?

Comment: Good job they don't write software for the AirBus 380 that way....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why would you want to force the user to reboot their phone? that is a terrible idea.
If the device's memory is full when your app tries to allocate some, the os will dump other apps from memory until yours and essential services are all that's left. And then you will receive a memory warning. At which point there is only your app, and essential services running. Rebooting the device won't fix this.

Comment: Cool. I didnt want to force one. I thought just a reminder message could be displayed.

Comment: This doesn't match my experience - either I'm allocating memory faster than the OS can free it, or something else wrong, but my app can consume 20+ MBs after a reboot but otherwise the OS terminates it far earlier, memory warnings or not.

Comment: If you are getting to that scenario, then likely you are leaking.  You should run a leak tool and plug them up.

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone, your view will receive `-(void) UIViewController:didReceiveMemoryWarning`, if you are  running low on memory, which will give the opportunity to purge any caches  necessary to free up more memory for your application. It's probably best to do that instead of refusing to start up if there isn't enough memory available a priori. Actually detecting the amount of available memory would be tricky, because although you might be able to get the maximum amount of memory that your process is allowed to allocate, some of that memory is going to be used by malloc and by the app framework.

PS. Forcing users to reboot is a horrible user experience, and your application will automatically be terminated if it runs out of memory, so there's is no good reason to force users to reboot.

Comment: Wait - "your application will automatically be terminated if it runs out of memory" and "there's is no good reason to force users to reboot" seem directly contradictory...

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what memory you are looking for: RAM or disk. But below code should help you to get what you are looking for. Ignore NSString* as return values. They were meant for easy printing.

```
- (NSString*) totalMemory
{
    NSString* v;
    v = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[UIDevice currentDevice] totalMemory]];
    return v;
}


- (NSString*) userMemory
{
    NSString* value;
    value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[UIDevice currentDevice] userMemory]];
    return value;
}


- (NSString*) freeMemory
{
    NSString* value;
    value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [UIDevice freeMemory]];
    return value;
}


- (NSString*) totalDiskSpace
{
    NSNumber* totDiskSpace= [[UIDevice currentDevice] totalDiskSpace];
    NSString* value = [totDiskSpace stringValue];
    return value;
}


- (NSString*) freeDiskSpace
{
    NSNumber* theFreeDiskSpace= [[UIDevice currentDevice] freeDiskSpace];
    NSString* value = [theFreeDiskSpace stringValue];
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Code is correct.  Suggestion that it would be useful in a real world app is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, so I hate to be a stick in the mud, but UIDevice doesn't have any of those methods listed in the documentation... are they private?

Comment: FYI: In XCode 5 this code will not compile with several errors that look like this: No visible @interface for 'UIDevice' declares the selector 'totalMemory'